# How to create a bootable install on USB with the minimal CD?

Tags: installation, usb

How can I create a bootable installer on USB with Ubuntu 11?

Comment: What environment are you in, Windows, Linux?

Comment: UNetbootin is pretty easy to use and works on Windows and Linux

Comment: @Uri Herrera, does it work with Ubuntu 11 Minimal tho?

Comment: i'm not sure, i tried to do a bootable disc for ubuntu studio but didn't work, though it may work now, seems t work only with livecds that come with a graphical installer.

Comment: Ubuntu 11? There are two releases of Ubuntu that begin with 11: 11.04 (Natty) and 11.10 (Oneiric).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu minimal does not work with Startup Disk Creator.

Use Unetbootin as per this [AU Question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42937/how-do-i-boot-a-minimal-cd-iso-from-a-usb-stick-and-use-a-wireless-driver/43279#43279).

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the Ubuntu iso you want installed on the usb.
2. Go to Adminstration;Startup Disk Creater.
3. Press the "Other" button and select the iso image.
4. Highlight your usb drive in the "Disk to use" box.
5. Click "Make Startup Disk"

Comment: I try that (Startup disk creator) with Ubuntu 11 Minimal but nothing happens are I select the iso

Comment: Everybody is saying that the "Minimal CD" does NOT work with Startup Disk Creator. Have you tried your suggestion, @ZachariahCallaway?

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using Windows and don't wish to burn the Live CD you can extract usb-creator.exe from the Ubuntu iso using 7zip.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'dd' will also work.  Make sure you know which /dev/sd ID your usb stick is.  To find out run Startup Disk Creator and it will show you.  I will use sdb for this example.  Unmount if mounted `umount /dev/sdb1` then from terminal run the command
`sudo dd if=mini.iso of=/dev/sdb`