# How do I boot a minimal CD ISO from a USB stick and use a wireless driver

Tags: 11.04, installation, wireless, ubuntu-minimal

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11 x64 minimal but I found that I dont have a wired ethernet connection (its broken) but I can possibly connect wirelessly.

Is it possible to use the minimal CD image and add the wireless driver?

In addition, I dont have an external CD Drive - will I be able to boot the minimal CD ISO from a USB drive?

Wireless is Intel Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN

Comment: So far as I know, if you're not using the [mini.iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) you mention there's no way to do this. You could do a lot of `apt-get remove` once you're done installing the 'full' version mind you. It's obviously not ideal though. What wireless chipset do you have? Do you have an ethernet port?

Comment: @boehj, wireless from intel Intel Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN... wired is what I'd prefer but its spoilt just recently ...

Comment: jiewmeng - "spoilt recently"?  Do you mean its broken?  If so, suggest get an ebay USB to RJ45 adapter so that you can install via wired.  Should cost only a couple of dollars.

Comment: @fossfreedom, I have been looking for it. Asked in many computer hardware stores. All so far only have USB/Wireless adapter, not Ethernet. The only ethernet 1 is from Apple, for MacBook Air I suppose? I am not sure it will work on PC tho ...

Comment: I imagine the Apple one will work but it'll just be over-priced. You could maybe ask at the store.

Comment: @fossfreedom, shipping will cost a large part of it tho :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The minimal CD ISO cannot be installed via the StartUp Disk Creator that comes as standard with Ubuntu.

However, you can download and install unetbootin from the software centre and install the minimal CD as per this picture

[image]

If the installation doesnt work because the wireless is not recognised, my recommendation would be to buy a USB-to-RJ45 adapter to fix - hopefully the limited kernel that comes with the minimal CD will recognise this adapter.  Should be very cheap to buy on ebay - just search for "usb to rj45" on you local ebay site...

Comment: Worked perfectly fine for me!