# Building a GNOME 3 based distribution from scratch?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing ubuntu desktop without all the bloat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42964/installing-ubuntu-desktop-without-all-the-bloat)

I have this idea of installing Ubuntu using the [minimal cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), and then installing GNOME 3 using the ppa. How viable is this? And how will my remix compare with distro's that already ship with GNOME 3 like Fedora or openSUSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very similar question as this [AU question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42964/installing-ubuntu-desktop-without-all-the-bloat).

You should note, adding Gnome3 onto Ubuntu 11.04 is not as "clean" as the new Fedora 15 - since this has been built with Gnome3 from the beginning.  Building ontop of Ubuntu means upgrading most of the Gnome-2 libraries.