# OEM version of ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I was wondering if there is an OEM version of Ubuntu like that of windows which has nothing but the necessities to operate. (ex no add-ins or any thing of the likes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an OEM install , see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview

Can you please clarify what you mean by "nothing but the necessities to operate"? If you want a bare bones install, use the mini iso

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Note : a minimal install will be command line only with a minimal number of packages

Or you can do a server install

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server

Sort of depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: The OEM install you linked is extremely outdated.

Comment: @nevelis - do you have a more recent link?

Comment: If I had, I would've posted it as an answer :) instead I'm posting a suggestion to improve your answer, to remove a link that applies to a release from nearly two years ago which doesn't work with the current 14.04 release.

Comment: The OEM link I gave is maintained "Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview (last edited 2014-05-04 20:16:05 by lorenzo567)" and the most up to date documentation available. If it is inaccurate, feel free to update as it is a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Installing ubuntu desktop without all the bloat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42964/installing-ubuntu-desktop-without-all-the-bloat)?  This shows you how to do an absolute bare-bones install of Gnome without anything extra installed.  It sounds like what you're looking for.

Edit:  I based my install off the second guys answer:  Download the netinstall ISO from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD - don't install any extra packages.  When you reboot, log into the console & run:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop synaptic gksu gdm
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I'll note that this link is 3 years old, but it worked for me yesterday with Ubuntu 14.04 - you can skip the section after "Now - if you want to install Gnome3 continue" as Gnome 3 is in the main repo.